# What is meant exactly by the "familiae Troianae"?

Tags: terminology

I have seen the term *familiae Troianae* mentioned in Pauly and elsewhere. It has something to do with Roman families and Trojan ancestry, but it seems to be a fixed and well known term: what does it mean exactly? Here it is in Pauly's article on *Iulus*:

[image]

Comment: In which context have you seen that? Is it a classical thing? If you have a use example, that would help me understand what the phrase might do.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta♦: Ah, I came across it in the article about *Iulus*, but I didn't want to spoil my other question...but I suppose you're right: I've added the context to my question.

Comment: Wikipedia says the following "Such was the fame of the Epic Cycle in Roman and Medieval times that it was built upon to provide a starting point for **various founding myths of national origins**. The most influential, Virgil's Aeneid, traces the journeys of the Trojan prince Aeneas, supposed ancestor of the founders of Rome and the Julio-Claudian dynasty. [...] a Trojan pedigree was both gloriously ancient and established an equality with the ruling class of Rome."